# Inner join not available in loopback 4

Tags: node.js, typescript, orm, loopback4

Associations are properly set & code is working but I am struggling with join type I want.

Below code is written to get only those addresses which have users having ids [260, 123].

```
const addresses = await this.addressRepository.find({
  include: [{
    relation: 'users',
    scope: {
      where: { id: { inq: [260, 123] } }
    }
  }]
})
```

But what I am getting is, all addresses with `where` filter applied only on users which works as left join.

Please help me to get query as per my need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, LB4 doesn't support SQL inner join (https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/4299).

Examples with instances and a simple reference to what are the relations would help us understand what you are trying to accomplish, what's the current output and what's the expected output.

I guess that the relation is **Address -> hasMany -> User

Example Instances:

```js
addresses = [{ id: 0 }, { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];
users = [
  { id: 0, addressId: 0 },
  { id: 1, /* no address */ },
  { id: 2, addressId: 1 }, // same as id 260
  { id: 260, adressId: 1 },
  { id: 123, addressId:2 }
];
```

Expected Result:

```js
[
  { id: 1, users: [{ id: 260 }] }
  { id: 2, users: [{ id: 123 }] },
]
```

Actual Result:

```js
[
  { id: 0, users: [] } // filtered out user with id = 0
  { id: 1, users: [{ id: 260 }] } // filtered out user with id = 2
  { id: 2, users: [{ id: 123 }] },
  { id: 3, users: [] }
]
```

So your query doesn't filter **Addresses** based on relation users and their userId (or **inner join**), but instead queries parent model (Address) based on current 'where' filter (matches all) and justs filters out the users from the include relation.

**Workaround 1**

One workaround could be to also add a **User -> BelongsTo -> Address** relation and use the reverse query:

```js
const users = await this.userRepository.find({
  where: {id: {inq: [260, 123]}},
  include: [{
    relation: 'address',
  }],
});
// now you only have to reduce the final users with their addresses into unique addresses.
```

Note: Don't forget to update the **UserRelations** as for belongsTo the relation is not automatically added:

```js
export interface UserRelations {
  // describe navigational properties here
  address?: AddressWithRelations;
}
```

**Workaround 2**

And of course, another workaround is to keep the list of **userIds** inside the addresses and query based on that property. Obviously, the downside with this is that when you update the user you must also update the corresponding address.

Comment: I already preferred first workaround but nice explaination. I am from `rails` background and activerecord is much stronger than this. So I am not happy with lb4 so much.

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you are using only one postgres datasource for the concerned queries we are working on this fork : https://github.com/Wikodit/loopback-connector-postgresql

it allows inner join query like :

```
{
  "where": {
    "user.contact.email": "mail@domain.tld",
    "profile.name": "support"
  },
  "include": [
    {
      "relation": "user",
      "scope": {
        "include" : [
           {
             "relation": "contact"
           }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "relation": "profile"
    }
  ],
  "order": "user.contact.email ASC"
}
```